# Hyperlink Visibility in MVVM and Prism

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, hyperlink, prism

I have a hyperlink for Logout and it should be hidden on the main page as user has not yet logged in. As soon as user is in, it should be visible.
I have replaced the text in Hyperlink with a textbox and set its content after checking the authentication.

Is there a way, by which we can set Visibilty of Hyperlink instead of using TextBox for its content?

**XAML Code :**

```
<TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10" Width="60">
        <Hyperlink Name="lnkLogOut" Focusable="True" FontSize="16" FontStyle="Normal" Command="{Binding LogOutCommand}" Foreground="#AC0000">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LogOutText}" />
            <!--Log Out--> // this was the static text before
        </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
```

**Model :**

```
private string _showlogOut = string.Empty;   
public string ShowlogOut
{
   get { return _showlogOut; }
   set
   {
       SetProperty(ref _showlogOut, value);
   }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
if (_isLoginSuccessful)
{
   ShowlogOut = "Log Out"; 
//.............other code...............
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either another (bool) property in the view model that you bind to the visibility of your log out hyperlink using `BoolToVisibilityConverter` or you create an `StringEmptyToVisibilityConverter` and use the existing property.